# How can I get shadows in blender game engine?

Tags: blender

I'm making a very simple game in blender and for some reason shadows don't work. I tried every kind of light source, including objects with emisions. 'Cast shadow' and 'recieve shadow' check boxes are checked for ol the objects. I tryed all teh methods to dysplay objects. Is there an easy way to get shadows in the game?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Viewport press N and in the rendering options switch from multitexture to GLSL and then switch to Texture mode,
You don't have to tweak the settings. you can try this by creating a new blend file.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 4):

Away to create shadows is like so:

-Switch Muiltitexture to GLSL

Now, you must understand that only certain lights cast shadows. I believe that the only two are the Sun, and Spotlight, however spotlight only casts partial.

While in GLSL Mode, you must change the Solid Mode to Textured Mode for lighting to work. Then, select the sun(angled at your prefered angle) and scroll down in the objects tab. Look for Shadows, and make sure the box is checked. Then play it. The Shadows should automatically appear in the Scene view as well because GLSL has support for realtime shadows.

WAY NUMBER 2:
Another way is to Bake a scene or object. This means that you place lighting in render mode, and capture all the lighting and textures(with lighting) and make a texture. This works really well, but doesn't have realtime shadows. Look it up for more imformation.

Hope this Helped!